# Facebook login behaviour - Chrome under Windows 8

Tags: facebook, authentication

Using FB.Login I have two different results in Chrome:
1. Start Chrome in Windows 8 mode - result is **new tab**
2. Relaunch Chrome on the Desktop - result is login form /OK/

Of course I can not ask users to switch mode.
Any ideas hot to solwe problem?

**UPDATE**
After removing channel file from FB init - It works fine - both modes show dialog, not new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing channel file from FB init - It works fine - both modes show dialog, not new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you make the javascript check if you are using IE10 or another browser.
Take a look at this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html